# are single redis commands executed in isolation?

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm using Node and Redis.

If I issue a redis.set() command, is there any chance that whilst that is being set, another read can occur with the old value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you will never have that problem. One of the basic virtues of Redis is that it has a tight event loop which executes the commands, so they are naturally atomic.

[This page](http://blog.mjrusso.com/2010/10/17/redis-from-the-ground-up.html#heading_toc_j_4) has more on the topic (see subheading "Atomicity"), and about Redis in general.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about two truly concurrent accesses, one write and one read, there is essentially no meaning to this question.  If a write is itself atomic and the value is never seen as anything other than the old or new value, then a reader who reads at "about the same time" as a writer may legitimately see either the old or the new value.